# getting garbage values when accessing the global variable

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, global-variables

I was trying to implement the functionality of `NewGlobalRef function` through the following code. The function in the following code is called by the Java code at a gap of 3 seconds. As the function is called it displays how many times it has been called.I do get the first output fine but the remaining outputs are some garbage values. I don't know the reason for this. Follow the outputs after the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Package_UsingGlobalVariable.h"

void Java_Package_UsingGlobalVariable_evaluator
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env,obj);
jfieldID fid = (*env)->GetFieldID(env,cls,"count","I");
jint count = (*env)->GetIntField(env,obj,fid);
jclass intGlbRef;
if(count == 0) {
    printf("Number of times this function has been accessed : %d\n",++count);
    (*env)->SetIntField(env,obj,fid,-1); // count changed to -1 : function has been accessed atleast once
    jclass intLclRef = (*env)->FindClass(env,"java/lang/Integer");
      if(intLclRef == NULL) {
        return NULL;
      }
    intGlbRef = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env,intLclRef);
    intGlbRef = count;
} else {
    jint c;
    c = (jint)intGlbRef;
    printf("Number of times this function has been accessed : %d\n",++c);
    intGlbRef = (jint)c;
    if( c == 3) {
        (*env)->DeleteGlobalRef(env,intGlbRef);
    }
}
}
```

*Output :*

```
Number of times this function has been accessed : 1
Number of times this function has been accessed : 25666561
Number of times this function has been accessed : 25666561
```

*Java code :*

```
public class UsingGlobalVariable {
private native void evaluator();
private int count;

public UsingGlobalVariable() {
    count = 0;
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    UsingGlobalVariable o = new UsingGlobalVariable();
    try {
        int i = 0;
        while(i<3) {
            o.evaluator();
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            i++;
        }
    }catch(Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}

static {
    System.loadLibrary("UsingGlobalVariable");
}
```

}

What is the problem in *C* code ?

Warning by the *C* compiler :

```
W:\elita\jnitesters\workspace\c\UsingGlobalVariable\UsingGlobalVariable.c|11|warning: format '%d' expects type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'jint'|
W:\elita\jnitesters\workspace\c\UsingGlobalVariable\UsingGlobalVariable.c|15|warning: 'return' with a value, in function returning void|
W:\elita\jnitesters\workspace\c\UsingGlobalVariable\UsingGlobalVariable.c|18|warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast|
W:\elita\jnitesters\workspace\c\UsingGlobalVariable\UsingGlobalVariable.c|22|warning: format '%d' expects type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'jint'|
W:\elita\jnitesters\workspace\c\UsingGlobalVariable\UsingGlobalVariable.c|23|warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast|
W:\elita\jnitesters\workspace\c\UsingGlobalVariable\UsingGlobalVariable.c|21|warning: 'intGlbRef' may be used uninitialized in this function|
||=== Build finished: 0 errors, 6 warnings ===|
```

The last warning could help solve the problem but i can't think of any other way else than declare `intglbRef` outside the if-else blocks. How should i declare it so i get `1,2,3` as the result ?

Comment: Did you look for the reasons for those warnings? Did you try and remove them? An example: `'return' with a value, in function returning void` probably means this line `return NULL;` (remove the `NULL` here). `assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast` probably means this line `intGlbRef = count` (I'm no JNI expert but I guess it would have to be something like `intGlbRef = &count`, or maybe `intGlbRef` should not have the type `jclass`), etc. etc.

Comment: @Thomas Earlier i tried the code without a cast,then after the warnings i gave a cast. The last warning could help solve this question but i can't think of any other way else than declare it outside the if-else blocks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You do know that `Integer` objects are not `int` values, and that the value enclosed by an `Integer` object cannot be changed?

Comment: @Joni Salonen I want the output to be `1,2,3`. At each call the function should tell how many times it has been called before. And i want to do this using `NewGlobalRef`

Comment: Why do you want to use `NewGlobalRef`? The easiest way to achieve this is with a global or static `int` (or `jint`) variable in C. What should the reference point to?

Comment: @Joni Salonen I want to feel the functionality of `NewGlobalRef` !